# How do you make Ubuntu accept files sent over bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have a problem when I send my files from phone to ubuntu 12.04 via bluetooth as the phone prompts with the message "the file not sent"! I can send any files from ubuntu 12.04 to my android phone.

Comment: Same issue for me on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. No solution so far...

Comment: Created a bug for this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-user-share/+bug/1406108

Comment: I would just like to confirm that on 18.04 the apt-get install blueman fixes the issue as well.

Answer (score 171):

Go to ***Dash Home*** search for ***personal file sharing***. If you don't have Unity installed, you can open the program from a terminal with typing `gnome-file-share-properties` in it.

[image: Ubuntu Personal File Sharing Bluetooth]

At the bottom of the box enable ***Receive files in downloads folder over bluetooth*** also enable ***Notify about received file*** then you're good to go :)

[image: Personal File Sharing Application Ubuntu Bluetooth Sharing]

Comment: How is the program name if I want to start that in a Terminal?

Comment: gnome-file-share-properties

Comment: this did not work for me on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Its worked for me on 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04. but didn't seen any notifications may be some error.

Comment: It only worked after rebooting both smartphone and computer (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit) @faizal

Comment: @FlorianEchtler This doesn't work in Xfce. What package needs to be installed?

Comment: gnome-user-share (can also be looked up using "dpkg -S gnome-file-share-properties").

Comment: Still works in Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: It doesn't work for me Ubuntu 15.10 I can send files but not receive

Comment: This worked for me without restart in 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04.5.  And the notification is just a sound (when transfer is complete).

Comment: In 18.04 LTS it looks like mate-file-share-properties is there in its place. <sigh>

Comment: It worked in 16.04 LTS 64 bit without reboot.

Comment: It should be possible to configure it using only "Bluetooth Settings".

Comment: Could we get an update for something that works in 18.04 (It is kind of bad that by far the most upvoted answer does not work anymore.)

Comment: on ubuntu 20 it needs to be installed from the Ubuntu Software, and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 13):

[Updated answer tested on Ubuntu 20.04]

I have found that simply installing blueman and using the blueman applet works well:

1. First, pair your device using the system default bluetooth menu.
2. Install blueman:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install blueman
   ```
3. Run the applet:

   ```
   /usr/bin/blueman-applet
   ```
4. Click on the new bluetooth applet indicator and select **Local Services** from the menu.
5. Tic the box for **Accept files from trusted devices** > select a default destination folder > and then click **Apply**.

[image: screenshot of the popup window for the Local Services options with the box ticked for Accept files from trusted devices. you also need to select a destination directory at this point or it will not allow you to click apply (not shown).]

5. Go back to the [other] system default bluetooth menu > hover your mouse cursor over your Phone/device > and toggle **Connection** before you send the file to Ubuntu.

[image: screenshot showing the dropdown menu from the default system bluetooth menu with the mouse cursor hovered over the phone/device and the switch is toggled for "Connection"]

Sharing from your phone should "just work".

**NOTE**: If the phone tries to send, but immediately fails, it may be a folder-permissions issue.  Files sent via bluetooth are downloaded temporarily to `~/.cache/obexd`, and if the owner/permissions  of this folder aren't set correctly, the files can't be downloaded there and the transfer fails.  Changing the folder's ownership and/or permissions so that your non-root account has read/write access to it should fix the problem.

---

[Original answer:]

For non-gnome/unity desktop-environments (Xmonad, XFCE, LXDE, etc.), the following works (tested on 15.04):

1. Make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install obex-data-server gnome-user-share
   ```
2. Run `gnome-file-share-properties` from the command-line, and make sure **Receive files in downloads folder over bluetooth** and **Notify about received file** are enabled.
3. Create a file `~/bin/start-bluetooth-listener` which contains the following (the order is important):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /usr/bin/obex-data-server
   /usr/lib/gnome-user-share/gnome-user-share &
   ```

   (create the`~/bin` directory first if it doesn't already exist)
4. Make the file executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/bin/start-bluetooth-listener
   ```
5. Either manually run the `~/bin/start-bluetooth-listener` script, or set up your desktop-environment to automatically run the script when you log-in (e.g. in XFCE, via the `xfce4-session-settings` tool).

Now if you try to send a file from your phone to your paired computer via bluetooth, it should work, and pop up a notification window after the file has been received.

Comment: in ubuntu-studio with xfce i get this error when run `./start-bluetooth-listener`:  ./start-bluetooth-listener: 3: ./start-bluetooth-listener: /usr/lib/gnome-user-share/gnome-user-share: not found

Comment: Have you installed both packages before you did it?

Comment: This almost worked for me but the magic glyph was running `/usr/lib/gnome-user-share/gnome-user-share-obexpush`. Maybe the file name has changed as there is not one without the -obexpush suffix.

Comment: Blueman works.  But it only lets me transfer pictures and not videos from my tablet.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Bluetooth Settings on Ubuntu 20.04]

On Ubuntu 20.04, remember that you have to keep the `Bluetooth Settings` open in order to receive files, otherwise Ubuntu will reject all transfers.

Comment: I'm running Lubuntu 20.04  I found that having ~/cache/obexd open in my file manager helped to insure that files were received.

Comment: I found that having the Bluetooth Devices dialog box open also helped ensure successful transfers.

Comment: In my case just opening settings didn't work, I had to connect to the sending device, then I'm able to receive files.

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all. Have the phone connected, can send to it, but not receive from it.

Answer (score -10):

go to bluetooth sittings and pair your device and choose the device that you want to send or connect audio speaker set shown and put sign on ( use your phone as, and send or play music

Comment: The question asked is regarding file transfer. You aren't addressing his problem with this solution.