# "connection unsuccessful" transfering a file via Bluetooth from Android phone

Tags: bluetooth

When I try to send a file from my Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone to my Ubuntu 12.10 PC, I get a message on the phone reading "connection unsuccessful". What might be the cause of this?

The devices are paired and I can succesfully send files from the PC to the phone.

Comment: Maybe you need to compress the file to send. Works fine with me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make Ubuntu accept files sent over bluetooth](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install [Blueman Bluetooth Manager](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman) from the software centre.

Works much better than the default bluetooth manager, I had the same issue as you with the default manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved several issues I had with Bluetooth. A bit disappointing that it doesn't work out of the box, though. (I mean, why not, when the solution is known anyway?)

Comment: Great software, but I have a very rare issue. I am able to pair devices, I paired my Android with my laptop, I'm able to explore the files via FTP with both native and blueman controllers, I'm able actually to play music from Phone to PC via bluetooth using blueman, but I'm not able to send a single file (a png photo) via bluetooth. It crashes with both controllers. Any idea?

Comment: Also a tip: Blueman stores recieved files in Home/Public

Comment: Blueman worked for me where standard bluetooth manager caused an error on sending machine and did not receive any file. Ubuntu 15.10 here

Answer (score 53):

Search and find "Personal File Sharing" in the dash and activate both check boxes under "Receive Files over Bluetooth". This way you won't have to install `blueman`.

Comment: "Go to Personal File Sharing" Where is this?

Comment: If you are unable to find it in a menu or using the 'dash', open a terminal window, and type "gnome-file-share-properties" followed by pressing enter.

Comment: Or, instead of opening terminal, just press Ctrl+F2 and type "gnome-file-share-properties", then press Enter :)

Comment: This worked for me! Still not able to browse phone's folders but at least I can send from the phone to computer... I don't know why people keep recommending to install Blueman, it seems to me that is only an applet and it hasn't solved any of my bluetooth problems so far.

Comment: do I have to uninstall blueman? wont conflict?

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer! Installing an additional software should never be the first solution!

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: I actually made a video regarding this issue in the past that is still relevant. Maybe you could try that? https://youtu.be/xEGtn_Cezyo

Comment: `gnome-file-share-properties` is not available on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to browse the apps for "Personal File Sharing" and select Receive files in Downloads folder over bluetooth. This will enable to send files/photos from your Andriod phone to Ubuntu. 
It worked for my xperia SL

Comment: How was this an improvement over [this pre-existing answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/235629/225694)

Answer (score 0):

Blueman seems nice, but all it did was reveal the error when transferring a file ("Connection refused"). After a bit of fiddling, what did the trick was **unpairing my phone from my laptop and pairing them again**.

Apparently, something in the previous pairing was set up incorrectly, although I've no idea what. :|

Comment: Perhaps if you were to [edit] this answer and include the steps you took "unpairing my phone from my laptop and pairing them again." This answer wouldn't be showing up in the low quality answer queue.

Comment: 2 years ago, no idea what the steps were: can't help you, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Use `rfkill` to ensure there isn't any hard/soft block on your bluetooth device. Issue:

```
rfkill list
```

If block is there, use the unblock option to unblock it:

```
rfkill unblock wlan1
```

Replace wlan1 with the type for your bluetooth device.

Refer http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/rfkill

Answer (score -2):

i config it through the dconf

make a search using ctrl+f and type in dialog box bluetooth
and enable the options that it list to you.

restart you PC and it work!!!

my laptop was with the same problem but it solve bluetooth problem!!!

i hope that solve you problem!!! Greetings!!!

Comment: the first option bluetooth-accept-files you must edit this value and type always, to receive files always :) sorry i don't put this details before !!!!

Comment: You can edit your answer to add that information.

Comment: Valeus, kkk :)!!!