# Cannot send files through bluetooth from mobile phone to laptop

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on my laptop.

Ubuntu detects bluetooth, and I can also send a file from Ubuntu laptop to my mobile phone (Nokia xpressMusic). But, I am unable to send files from mobile phone to laptop. I have tried making the ubuntu device visible. Yet I am unable to figure this out. Does anybody also have the same problem? Can someone help me.

My mobile says "Service not supported by other device". I have made my laptop visible on bluetooth, yet I am unable to.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/211006/connection-unsuccessful-transfering-a-file-via-bluetooth-from-android-phone

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth

Comment: Are you using Blueman on the Ubuntu desktop?