# Receiving files via bluetooth

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I am able to send files vie Bluetooth from my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop to an Android/Samsung phone. So I have set up that phone successfully as a device.

However, I am unable to receive files sent from my phone. For this, I select on my phone my Ubuntu laptop which is listed as present and send the file which results in failure after a few seconds.

Conversely I try to "Select device to browse" on my laptop, but my phone is not shown.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/235629/119823) did it without any extra installation.

Comment: Have a look at this thread [Bluetooth files in ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make Ubuntu accept files sent over bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. you can install blue-tooth manager from Ubuntu software center.

Comment: @Pabi: I believe this is an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)