# bluetooth on acer travelmate laptop can send only, but don't want to receive

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, acer

I have a acer travelmate 5720 laptop that runs ubuntu 13.04. It has built in bluetooth. For what I can see is that Ubuntu did pick up the bluetooth and the necessary bluetooth drivers is installed. But I'm only able to send files from this laptop to bluetooth devices, but for some reason I can't do the same visa verso to the laptop, for example if I try to send a file from a blackberry 9360 it can't send, tells me failed to find service. It kicks out. I try to find more drivers to install, tried a few in ubuntu software center, but no success. I even uninstalled all bluetooth drivers and reinstalled it, but no success, it doesn't pick up any phone anymore. Please assist me.

Comment: You need to enable "Receive files in downloads folder over bluetooth" http://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

install `blueman` :

> sudo apt-get install blueman

that fixed it for me

Comment: I tried it, but I still have the same problem. something else to try?

Comment: have you tried with another bluetooth device ?

Comment: I've tried a external device, I somewhat got it right to be able to send from the laptop to a blackberry. But it is still not working as it suppose to be. Will it work to uninstall all the bluetooth drivers, restart and reinstall it and see if the internal bluetooth works properly again?