# Ubuntu won't accept files over bluetooth, i have tried changing settings in personal file sharing

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, android, 15.10

When i want to send a file from my nexus 7 (android 6.0) it fails to send the file, and my nexus 7 says the transfer is forbidden by the target device.
I can send files, but not receive them.

I have tried the solution in this thread: [How do you make Ubuntu accept files sent over bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth)

But that does not work, what can i do?

pic of my personal file sharing settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN1gw.jpg

Bluetooth settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAzbC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

One package that isn't listed in your linked thread is obexftp and you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install obexftp
```

Then see if your bluetooth transfers work

The obexftp package provides object exchange file transfer protocol which is needed for bluetooth and other file transfers.

Comment: Make no difference for me.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 might be a lost cause as far as incoming bluetooth transfers are concerned.  File a bug report