# How to send files from Android to Ubuntu over Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

How to send files from Android to Ubuntu over Bluetooth?

Comment: Ooops ! Sorry I did not see the previous comment !

Answer (score 1):

You must enable *Personal File Sharing* over bluetooth

See [How do you make Ubuntu accept files sent over bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth)

Comment: Also After Personal File Sharing I cannot send files from Android to Ubuntu over Bluetooth. Why?

Comment: Do you see your computer in the list of available devices, when you are trying to share a file from your Android ?