# Ubuntu 16.10: Bluetooth not working properly

Tags: bluetooth, 16.10

After upgrading to 16.10 Bluetooth doesn't work properly. I can pair my Ubuntu with other Bluetooth devices, I can also play music from my phone or connect and use it with my Bluetooth headphone. But I'm not able to send/receive files. How can I solve this problem?

[image: sudo service bluetooth status]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth

Comment: @quest No, it's not. I have set personal file sharing to receive files. But I can't send or receive files.