# The bluetooth service cannot not restart properly : needs to be done in two steps

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, systemd

The bluetooth service cannot not restart properly :

```bash
$ sudo service bluetooth restart;service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since jeu. 2020-02-27 11:18:05 CET; 398ms ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 18310 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─18310 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: Sap driver initialization failed.
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 27 11:18:05 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18310]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
```

It needs to be done in two steps (see the last line of the `status`) :

```bash
$ sudo service bluetooth stop;sudo service bluetooth start;service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since jeu. 2020-02-27 11:20:12 CET; 2s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 18390 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─18390 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: Sap driver initialization failed.
févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 27 11:20:12 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18390]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
févr. 27 11:20:15 sebastien-B206 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
```

I tried adding the `RestartSec=5` parameter in the `[Service]` section of `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` (`man systemd.service`) but it didn't work :

```bash
$ sudo systemctl edit --full bluetooth
$ systemctl cat bluetooth | grep RestartSec
RestartSec=5
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo service bluetooth restart;service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since jeu. 2020-02-27 11:30:28 CET; 524ms ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 18830 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─18830 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: Sap driver initialization failed.
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 27 11:30:28 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[18830]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
```

Here is my `bluetooth.service` configuration :

```bash
$ systemctl cat bluetooth
# /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth service
Documentation=man:bluetoothd(8)
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.bluez
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
NotifyAccess=main
#WatchdogSec=10
#Restart=on-failure
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNPROC=1
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target,suspend.target
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.service
```

EDIT0 : Just rebooted then :

```bash
$ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
$ systemctl status -n 20 bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since jeu. 2020-02-27 17:23:24 CET; 2min 42s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 5050 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─5050 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

févr. 27 17:23:24 sebastien-B206 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Starting SDP server
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 initialized
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Error adding Link Loss service
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Current Time Service could not be registered
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Sap driver initialization failed.
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.65 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.65 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.42 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.42 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 27 17:23:25 sebastien-B206 bluetoothd[5050]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
```

EDIT1 : `rfkill list` output :

```bash
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT2 : Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213619/426176) but it didn't solve the `RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)` pb.

CONCLUSION : I added the `--noplugin=sap` option to the `ExecStart=` command line from a [solution proposed by @6666](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99920/115371) and it solved my restart pb. Still have the other errors but bluetooth is working fine after each bluetooth service restart so who cares about them :-)

Comment: @Gryu Added EDIT0

Comment: @Gryu Added EDIT1

Comment: @Gryu Still have the same errors in `journalctl -u bluetooth -n 20`

Comment: @Gryu I need to restart the bluetooth service after each resume, actually. Otherwise bluetooth connections won't work. You can take a look at https://superuser.com/q/1528786/528454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focus on the first substantial error [Sap driver initialization failed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40839/sap-error-on-bluetooth-service-status/99920#99920) since it cascades into the last error you highlighted:

`RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)`.

Start debugging top-down. Usually then the last errors solve themselves. For general referencing, [here](https://pythonhosted.org/BT-Manager/config.html) are some sample bluetooth config files for audio.

Comment: I added the `--noplugin=sap` option to the `ExecStart=` command line from a [solution you previously proposed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99920/115371) and it solved my restart pb. Still have the other errors but bluetooth is working fine after each bluetooth service restart so who cares about them :-) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Ok great,  just thought it looked right but didn't test it myself. Then I will add the link and modify the answer body! Could you connect your Headset?

Comment: Yep. I'm waiting for you to do that so I can upvote your answer.

Comment: Fantastic I'm glad to hear it!